# MS CRM 2013 Process Update Account - multiple values to one field

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to implement an update procedure like the one in this blog post (via extra entity and workflow updating account, triggered when the new entity is being created)
http://www.powerobjects.com/2013/08/01/updating-records-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/

In my list and the new entity "Account Update" I have 3 fields for the full name of a company (name, name_2, name_3).

In my workflow I want to put these 3 together and combine their values in the Account field "Company" (the company's name).
In the process I tried to insert them via the "Form Assistant" and in the field "Company" I now have the following entry:

> {Name(Account Update);Name_2(Account Update);Name_3(Account Update)}

but it doesn't seem to work. After my import and update of the account (which ends successful) the value in "Company" is only the value of the first name field.

Is it possible to combine values?
What exactly does it do, when I choose more than one field in the Form Assistant and say OK?

Comment: Looks like the first non-empty value is used. In this situation, I'd merge data beforehand, in the excel file itself (would be easier and faster).

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.
But if there is an option which I just don't know I could use the list as it is and let crm do the work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at last I figured out how to archive it.

With the "Form Assistant" you can combine or add multiple field values to one new field but it is a bit tricky.

The value in the process update the properies have to look like this:

> {Name(Account Update)} {Name_2(Account Update)}  {Name_3(Account Update)}

**BUT** 
It does not work if you enter this as text, you have to add the fields one after another so that they are recognized as fields (and marked yellow).

Click into the field (here: "Company").
Then choose the first field in the Form Assistant. Click "Add", choose it in the list below and click "OK". Now the field is in the field "Company".

Now go behind the end of the text in the field make a space and then choose and add the second field (clear the list in the Form Assistant before so that now only the second field is in the list)
So it's right if it looks like:

> {Name(Account Update)} {Name_2(Account Update)}

Wrong if looks like following (happens when you keep the first field in the list before adding the second with "OK")

> {Name(Account Update);Name_2(Account Update)}